# Dynamic / parsing of Json Objects

Tags: c#

In the following snippet I do not understand the difference between the code underneath the "//this fails", and the code under "//this works" (which is provided as boilerplate code when creating an Azure function.) NOTE: I realize that the cast to object isn't necessary, BUT ReadAsAsync returns object....

```
public static class FunctionTest
{
    [FunctionName("TestFunction")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        // parse query parameter
        string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
          .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
          .Value;

        //if nothing in the query parameter - lets' look into the body
        if (name == null)
        {
            //this fails
            dynamic abc = (object) @"{""name"":""test""}";
            string test = abc?.name;

            // this works
            dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
            name = data?.name;
        }

        return name == null
          ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body")
          : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + name);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is error message?

Comment: Error message:  Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'name'.

Comment: And that is correct. The string is not json (or xml or yaml ...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line:

```
dynamic abc = (object) @"{""name"":""test""}";
```

will take a `string` value and cast it into an `object`. That doesn't mean that it will treat the string as JSON and make a new dynamic object with a `name` property. It's still a `string` and the contents don't matter.

The second line however:

```
dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
```

calls the `ReadAsAsync` method with a generic type of `object`. This actually gives you a [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) cast as an `object` with various properties meaning that you could do this:

```
name = data["name"];
```

And because it is `dynamic`, that effectively translates your code into the above. However, almost every time I see `dynamic`, it's a code smell and this is no difference. Instead make a concrete class with the right properties and use that. That way you will have compile time type checking instead of relying on the dynamic object. For example:

```
public class Foo    {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Foo data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<Foo>();
```

Comment: I get what you are saying, but I disagree that ReadAsAsync is really a JObject.  JObject is an object defined by Newtonsoft, and hence I sure the .Net framework would not cast that to Object, which then works with dynamic.  Do you have any reference documentation that actually says its returning a Jobject??

Comment: Your RIGHT! 
? data.GetType() on the field that was returned from ReadAsAsync!!!
{Name = "JObject" FullName = "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject"}

Comment: Newtonsoft had been part of the MVC template for many years now.

Comment: so why return it as object? why not return it as a jobject?

Comment: Your code is responsible for specifying it as an object.